# Promise.all() and parallel promises are they differ in node

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a scenario where I can implement my code to make axios requests in two ways

### 1st way

```js
const data = {};

try {

  if (searchArray.includes('address')) {
    const address = await axios('./getAddress')
    data.addresses = address.data;
  }

  if (searchArray.includes('email')) {
    const email = await axios('./email')
    data.emails = email.data;
  }

  if (searchArray.includes('phone')) {
    const phoneNumber = await axios('./phone')
    data.phoneNumbers = phoneNumber.data;

  }
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(constants.HTTP_SERVER_ERROR).json(err);
}

res.status(200).json(data);
```

### 2nd Way

```js
const data = {};
const promises = []

if (searchArray.includes('address')) {
  promises.push(axios('./getAddress'))
}

if (searchArray.includes('email')) {
  promises.push(axios('./email'))
}

if (searchArray.includes('phone')) {
  promises.push(axios('./phone'))
}

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    res.status(200).json(results);
  })
  .catch(err) {
    return res.status(constants.HTTP_SERVER_ERROR).json(err);
  }
```

Which is the better approach? and why?

I prefer 1st approach because I can have well structured data than complete array of results. But got suggestion to implement sequentially than parallel

I assume node is single threaded so didn't find any difference in implementing it (I might be wrong if I use async and await)

Comment: The second appropach is definitely better because all the asynchronous operations run at once, instead of having to unnecessarily wait for the previous one to resolve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second approach will be more performant.

In the first example assume that each request takes 1 second to return, so you will take at least 3+ seconds to return your results as you wait for the result of one request before making the next.

In the second approach you make all the requests at once, and then wait for the IO callback. Once all the requests are handled the `Promise.all()` will resolve. If each request takes ~1 sec but is made in parallel your response will be about 1 second as well.

I would use syntax like the following however to maintain readability as you seem to be using `async/await` and don't need to have a reference to the `promises`.

```
try {
  const [addresses, emails, phones] = await Promise.all([
    searchArray.includes('address') 
      ? axios('./getAddress') : Promise.resolve({}),
    searchArray.includes('email') 
      ? axios('./email') : Promise.resolve({}),
    searchArray.includes('phone') 
      ? axios('./phone') : Promise.resolve({}),
  ]);
  return res.status(200).json({
     addresses: addresses.data,
     emails: emails.data,
     phoneNumbers: phones.data,
  });
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(constants.HTTP_SERVER_ERROR).json(err);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The statement "Javascript is single threaded" often confuses people.

While the main thread of code execution is single threaded, async executions are not usually handled by main thread. So basically when you execute few async tasks in series vs parallel, parallel execution is going to be faster for sure.

We go for async await approach sometimes if we need to wrap a number of dependent async operations in a single promise. Independent async operations should be executed in parallel.

Comment: It's worth noting that IO in Node *is not* single threaded. The node process itself is, but it isn't blocked by IO requests and will move on until there is a callback from the IO subsystem. It should be nearly as fast to make 3 requests as it is to make 1 request because the REST call can be made in parallel and Node has already moved on.

Comment: Of course... The thing is usually we do it for IO operations... but virtually any piece of code can be made async and hence be run in parallel.

Comment: That's not true actually unless you just mean the `async/await` syntax, but if it is blocking the node thread it will be run sequentially, not in parallel, and then resolve. Only calls outside the node process - notably I/O - can be parallelized (ignoring things like the `cluster` module) and then the results are returned via a callback to the node thread. Something CPU heavy like calculating a bunch of hashes in a `Promise.all()` will take the same amount of time as calculating them sequentially.

Comment: Actually i was talking rather in terms of worker thread and events to resolve corresponding promises in main thread.

Comment: Yeah, you could wrap the code with `cluster` and `generic-pool` and get the results via IPC messages, but it's often not worth the overhead and complexity unless you are doing something really specific and CPU intensive. For something like an `express` app I think it usually makes more sense to use `cluster` or `pm2` to run multiple isolated instances and do any intensive calculations asynchronously of requests.

Comment: I know and concur... Thats why i said virtually... Practically it doesn't make much sense

Comment: But I should also say you are 100% right that you can architect a Node app to use all of the available CPU cores if that's something you wanted to do.

Comment: Actually node process manager like pm2, forever or supervisor does exactly the same as u said earlier

Comment: You could get wild and run one `cluster` worker per core but also spin up an additional threadpool of workers (one per core) and if you had CPU intensive things to do (like hashes) so you could pass them off to the threadpool to get better performance assuming not all of the "main" worker threads are busy at the same time. Ahhhh, random application architectures :)