# Sequential axios requests in a map

Tags: javascript, axios

```
function SendObj(id, language) {
    setObjSending(true);
    Promise.all(
      objBoxes.map((box) => {
        return axios
          .post('/panel/subtask/paint-object/', {
            language: language,
            details: 'paint object',
            sub_task_paint: id,
            sub_task_color: [box.colorId],
            image_name: box.image_name,
          })
          .catch(() => setObjSending(false));
      })
    )
      .then(() => {
        message.success('subtask saved!');
        history.goBack();
      });
  }
```

The above function makes the produced Ids in database to be not in order of box indexes. Is there a way to do the axios call sequentially to fix this?

Comment: You [shouldn't and can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/8376184) make it *synchronous*, what you want is to make them *sequential*...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait for one fetch to finish before starting the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492609/wait-for-one-fetch-to-finish-before-starting-the-next) (It uses `fetch` instead of `axios`, but it's quite the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the `objBoxes` using `for` and await for each axios request.

```js
async function SendObj(id, language) {
  setObjSending(true);
  for (let i = 0; i < objBoxes.length; i++) {
    await axios
      .post('/panel/subtask/paint-object/', {
        language: language,
        details: 'paint object',
        sub_task_paint: id,
        sub_task_color: [objBoxes[i].colorId],
        image_name: objBoxes[i].image_name,
      })
      .catch(() => setObjSending(false));
  }
  message.success('subtask saved!');
  history.goBack();
}
```

Comment: This code makes requests one by one, sequentially. It can be done in parallels with Promise.all

Comment: @IvanD where should I put Promice.all?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767230/promise-all-and-parallel-promises-are-they-differ-in-node